# PineScript error: The study references too many candles in history

Tags: pine-script

I was recently working on an simple Pine Script indicator that is based on a fractals.
Fractals are really easy to understand here is the code which explains everything

`dnFractal(period) => (high[period-1] < high[period]) and (high[period+1] < high[period])  upFractal(period) => (low[period-1] > low[period]) and (low[period+1] > low[period])`

So my idea right now is to simply plot a diamond on top of the **Down Fractal** that is located between **Upper Fractals**.

My code is

```
//@version=5

indicator("Fractals", "FRAC", true)

n = input.int(title="Periods", defval=2, minval=2)

// ============ Logic ============

dnFractal(period) => (high[period-1] < high[period]) and (high[period+1] < high[period]) 
upFractal(period) => (low[period-1] > low[period]) and (low[period+1] > low[period])


first_appearance(right_limit) =>
    i = right_limit
    while (not dnFractal(i)) or (not upFractal(i))
        i := i + 1
    upCond = upFractal(i)
    dnCond = dnFractal(i)
    if upCond and dnCond
        [0, i]
    else if upCond
        [1, i]
    else if dnCond
        [-1, i]


entry = false
if upFractal(n)
    [res1, bar1] = first_appearance(n+1)
    if res1 == -1
        [res2, bar2] = first_appearance(bar1+1)
        if res2 == 1
            entry := true
    

// ============ End of Logic ============

// ============ Plotting ============
plotshape(dnFractal(n), style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar,  offset=-n, color=color.black)
plotshape(upFractal(n), style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar,  offset=-n, color=color.black)
plotshape(entry, "First entries", color=color.orange, style = shape.diamond, location = location.abovebar, offset = -n)
// ============ End of Plotting ============
```

However, it throws and error saying *The study references too many candles in history.*

I'm new to Pine Script so I don't really know if this code is written well or not (please give an advice if you have a better approach in mind) though I've got no idea where this error comes from

Everything, but nothing helps(

Comment: The issue may lie in the value of `right_limit` being too large. Where is that variable defined? Have you tried reducing that integer?

Answer (score 0):

The while loop makes infinite i if upfractal and downfractal conditions not to be satisfied. Add a breaking loop line like this.

```
first_appearance(right_limit) =>
i = right_limit
while (not dnFractal(i)) or (not upFractal(i))
    i := i + 1
    if i > 4900 // Added.
        break
```